# JMeter zoomed out too far

Tags: jmeter

If I startup JMeter it is zoomed out way too far on my big screen. I can zoom in a lot times, but isn't there a setting to correct this?:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your operating system is windows system：

1.open \bin\user.properties

add

```
jmeter.hidpi.mode=true
jmeter.toolbar.icons.size=32x32
jmeter.tree.icons.size=24x24
jsyntaxtextarea.font.family=Hack
jsyntaxtextarea.font.size=28
jmeter.hidpi.scale.factor=1.8
```

3. open \bin\jmeter.bat

add

```
set JVM_ARGS=%JVM_ARGS% -Dswing.plaf.metal.controlFont=Dialog-20
set JVM_ARGS=%JVM_ARGS% -Dswing.plaf.metal.systemFont=Dialog-20
set JVM_ARGS=%JVM_ARGS% -Dswing.plaf.metal.userFont=SansSerif-20
set JVM_ARGS=%JVM_ARGS% -Dswing.plaf.metal.smallFont=SansSerif-20
```

4.start jmeter

Options  ->  Look and Feel -> Metal

5.restart jmeter

Set to the appearance from the beginning of Darklaf, which will be restored after reboot. Therefore, on high-resolution screens, setting it to Metal mode should be a good way.

Comment: It seems zoomed in a lot more, but still I need to zoom once to have a normal view. Do I need to set the scale factor little higher in the user.properties?

Comment: If you need to set the font larger, you can modify the last number 20 in jmeter.bat to 28

Answer (score 0):

1. [You should be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so try upgrading to [JMeter 5.4.3](https://lists.apache.org/thread/dbg1bxywcwx5vtdwqf8ownf7ppgqjn41) or even to [nightly build](https://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html)
2. Try [upgrading your Java runtime to the most recent version](https://openjdk.java.net/), it might be the case it's Java unable to properly render the elements due to lack of high resolutions support
3. Play with `jmeter.hidpi.mode` and `jmeter.hidpi.scale.factor` [JMeter Properties](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/), see [Toolbar Display](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#toolbar_display) related ones in JMeter Documentation
4. Your "big" screen isn't very informative, going forward include screen resolution and ppi.